# dlopen and implicit library loading: two copies of the same library

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have 3 things: open source application (let's call it APP),
closed source shared library (let's call it OPENGL)
and open source plugin for OPENGL (let's call it PLUGIN)[also shared library].
OS: Linux.

There is need to share data between APP and PLUGIN,
so APP linking with PLUGIN, and when I run it,
system load it automatically.

After that APP call eglInitialize that belongs to OPENGL,
and after that this function load PLUGIN again.

And after that I have two copies of PLUGIN in the APP memory.

I know that because of PLUGIN have global data, and after debugging
I saw that there are two copies of global data.

So question how I can fix this behaviour?
I want one instance of PLUGIN, that used by APP and OPENGL.
And I can not change OPENGL library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that OPENGL is loading PLUGIN with the `RTLD_LOCAL` flag.  This
is normally what you want when loading a plugin, so that multiple
plugins don't conflict.

We've had similar problems with loading code under Java: we'd load a
dozen or so different modules, and they couldn't communicate with one
another.  It's possible that our solution would work for you: we wrote a
wrapper for the plugin, and told Java that the wrapper was the plugin.
That plugin then loaded each of the other shared objects, using `dlopen`
with `RTLD_GLOBAL`.  This worked between plugins.  I'm not sure that it
will allow the plugins to get back to the main, however (but I think it
should).  And IIRC, you'll need special options when linking main for
its symbols to be available.  I think Linux treats the symbols in main
as if main had been loaded with `RTLD_LOCAL` otherwise.  (Maybe
`--export-dynamic`?  It's been a while since I've had to do this, and I
can't remember exactly.)

Comment: I suppose you almost near the real solution. The problem was in RTLD_LOCAL. OPENGL call dlopen for PLUGIN.so.1. APP link with PLUGIN.so. After scp to machine PLUGIN.so became not soft link to PLUGIN.so.1, but real file. So I have two files PLUGIN.so and PLUGIN.so.1 in adress space of process.

Answer (score 2):

It obviously depends a lot on exactly what the libraries are doing, but in general some solution should be possible.

First note that normally if a shared library with the same name is loaded multiple times it will continue to use the same library. This of coruse primarily applies to loading via the standard loading/linking mechanism. If the library calls `dlopen` on its own it still can get the same library but it depends on the flags to `dlopen`. Try reading the docs on dlopen to get an understanding of how it works and how you can manipulate it.

You can also try positioning the PLUGIN earlier in the linker command so that it gets loaded first and thus might avoid a double load later one. If you must load the PLUGIN dynamically this obviously won't help. You can also check if `LD_PRELOAD` might resolve the linking order.

As a last resort you may have to resort to using `LD_LIBARY_PATH` and putting an interface library in from of the real one. This one will simply pass calls to the real one but will intercept duplicate loads and shunt them to the previous load.

This is just a general direction to consider. Your actual answer will depend highly on your code and what the other shared libraries do. Always investigate linker load ordering first, as it is the easiest to check, and then dlopen flags, before going into the other options.